Azure AI Studio - Issue with Index Storage and Azure AI Search Service Dropdown
I am working with Azure AI Studio and encountering an issue while setting up indexes. Here are the steps I've followed:


Under Components > Data, I clicked on "New data". In the Data source, I chose "Upload files/folders" and added various file types like .docx and .txt, then clicked on create. The files now appear as expected.
I then selected Indexes under components and clicked on "New Index". For the Data source, I chose "Data in Azure AI Studio" and selected the folder containing my files.
When I proceeded to the next step, I noticed the "Index storage" option is greyed out.
Additionally, under "Select Azure AI Search service", there is no dropdown option available, even though I have already created an Azure AI Search service.

Could anyone help me understand why the "Index storage" is greyed out and why there is no dropdown option for the Azure AI Search service? What might I be missing in my setup?
Thanks in advance for your assistance!
I have created an AI Search Service so I would have expected this to appear on the drop down?


Could anyone help me understand why the "Index storage" is greyed out and why there is no dropdown option for the Azure AI Search service?

Firstly, create azure ai search resource in portal with the required data.

Navigate to Azure AI Services and below you can find AI search resource then create a new resource.


Then, Go to Azure AI Studio create data (new data) as below.

I have taken a sample pdf file for testing my resource.

Click on Indexes to create a new indexes taken data sources "Data in Azure AI Studio".



Now, Iam able to see the AzureAISearch in the dropdown box as you can check below.


The reason is that you didn't create a resource in the portal before creating indexes. You can create directly in the same tab only check this Image.

Hi, thanks for getting back to me, I've done it both ways so I originally created an Azure AI Search on my Resource Group (using the free tier) and then I created another Azure AI Search (Using the next Tier after the free version) via when creating a Index and still both do not appear.

It has to be appeared after changing to the basic plan, Actually I am using standard tier please try this. Refresh twice after done this activity.
